# How to check whether the current web user is an actual user and not a crawler

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, httpwebrequest, security, httprequest

Is there an accurate way to check whether the current user viewing my site is an actual user not just a crawler. Suppose I write some code in my ASP.Net application to download some page from any website, but how would that application know that I am downloading the pages.

I have tried to put a timer which will record his last access time, but I would like a better approach if possible. This question is a kind of security. I have done some R&D such as sending a unique identificaiton number with every page and return to web server in another request, but this is not a good approach. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Not with any real accuracy. You might assume you have a crawler when a unique IP read every page in site in under 2 seconds, though it may also be a browser add-on that caches in advance.

Many crawlers identify themselves with the headers they send, but that doesn't mean ALL crawlers do that, and there are many questions on how to spoof headers to appear like something you are not (old example is pretending to be a version of Internet Explorer in order for some sites to give you data).

Also, a user could use PHP to pretend to be one of the crawlers by copying the headers, and grabbing all the content in a similar manner.

If this is around security, you'd best avoid relying on whatever the client tells you that it is and try another approach (registering / logging in / credit card if you are really serious)